# Another... 500 internal server PHP

Tags: php, sql

Been reading almost all of the error 500 internal questions here in SO, but still cant figure out whats app with mine.

This is the error message i get..

```
Server error
The website encountered an error while retrieving http://www.pixeltouch.no/book/register.php. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this webpage later.
HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.
```

I have looking at my codes for a while but still cant find the problem.

Any luck here ?

This is my login.php

```
 <?php 
 include('/core/inc/init.inc.php');


$errors = array();

if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])){
    if(empty($_POST['username'])){
        $errors[] = 'The username cannot be empty.';    
    }
        if(empty($_POST['password'])){
        $errors[] = 'The password cannot be empty.';
    }
//Log in
    if (valid_credentials($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']) == false ){
        $errors[] = 'Username / Password incorrect.';
    }
        if (empty($errors)){
            $_SESSION['username'] = htmlentities($_POST['username']);
            $_SESSION['uid'] = fetch_user_id($_SESSION['username']);

            header("Location: profile.php?uid=" . $_SESSION['uid']);
                die();
                echo $_SESSION['uid'];
        }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
<title>Pixeltouch</title> 

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ext/style.css" />

</head> 
<body> 
<div id="page-wrap"> 
<div id="main-content"> 
<br/>
<?php include_once('template/head.inc.php');
?>
<div id="menu"> 

<?php include_once('template/nav.inc.php');
?> 

</div> 
<!-- SKRIVBOX-->

<div>
<?php 
if(empty($errors) == false){
?>
<ul>

<?php

foreach ($errors as $error) {
    echo "<li>$error</li>";
}

?>
</ul>

<?php

}else{
echo 'Need an account ? <a href="register.php">Register here</a>'; 
}

?>



</div>
<br/>
<form method="post" action="" >
<p>
<label for="username">Username:</label>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['username'])) echo  htmlentities($_POST['username']); ?>" />
</p>
<p>
<label for="password">Password: </label>
<input type="password" name="password"  id="password" />
</p>
<p>
<input type="submit" value="Login" />
</p>

</form>


<!-- SKRIVBOX END-->
</div> 

<?php include_once('template/foot.inc.php');
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And my Init.inc.php file

```
 <?php
 session_start();

 mysql_connect("SERVER", "USERNAME", "PASSW") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
 mysql_select_db("pixeltouch2") or die(mysql_error()) ;

 $path = dirname(__FILE__);
 include("{$path}/user.inc.php");

 ?>


                                    <!--Registration/Login (START)-->
 <?php 


 $exceptions = array('register', 'login', 'user_list', 'profile', 'edit_profile');

 $page = substr(end(explode('/', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])), 0, -4);

 if(in_array($page, $exceptions) == false){
    if (isset($_SESSION['username']) == false){
    header('Location: login.php');
    die();
    }
  }
 ?>

                                    <!--Registration/Login (END)--> 


                                        <!--User Profile (START)-->
 <?php
 $_SESSION['uid'] = 1;


 ?>

                                        <!--User Profile (END)-->
```

I Got the Error logg from the webb hosters and it says

> [Thu May 24 11:31:24 2012] [error] Warning:
>   include(/core/inc/init.inc.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream:
>   No such file or directory in /home/3/p/pixeltouch/www/book/login.php
>   on line 2, referer: http://www.pixeltouch.no/book/login.php  [Thu May
>   24 11:31:24 2012] [error] PHP Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening
>   '/core/inc/init.inc.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5.2-suphp/lib/php') in
>   /home/3/p/pixeltouch/www/book/login.php on line 2, referer:
>   http://www.pixeltouch.no/book/login.php  [Thu May 24 11:31:24 2012]
>   [error] PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function
>   valid_credentials() in /home/3/p/pixeltouch/www/book/login.php on line
>   22, referer: http://www.pixeltouch.no/book/login.php

Comment: What do your server logs say??

Comment: Hmm, Where can i find the logs ?

Comment: That depends on your webserver stack. Apache on Linux? Windows? IIS? Nginx? Search your documentation and/or online manual for the location. Typically for apache this will be a file called `error_log`; on Linux, this location is normally `/var/log/apache/`

Comment: Its an Linux server, But I cant find var/log/apache.

remember now that im the newest noob in the world :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem lies here:

```
include('/core/inc/init.inc.php');
```

The leading '/' is attempting to include the file from the root directory of your server. Try without the /. The path should be relative to the directory where register.php is located in this case.

Comment: It's actually relative to the current directory, whichever that might be when the script is run. If it's run by Apache, it will likely change the directory. It's best practice to use `dirname(__FILE__)` (or `__DIR__`) to make sure it's relative to the current script.

Comment: If I remove the / , I wont get the error message but I just enter an empty page :( . and it wont redirect to the profile as it does when i run it locally =/

Comment: A failed `include` won't kill a script. at most it'll issue a warning. If it was a `require`, then the script would abort if the path was incorrect or the file otherwise not reachable/readable.

Comment: To what should i change the dirname ?
Been trying different options but still the same error =/

Comment: Another thing i discovered is that when i remove the / from the include in the register.php .. is that when i register a username its saves the data in the sql ... But the page is still blank and it wont redirect to the profile site :(  .. but anyhow I have the same error in the profile site :(